# How to properly program a "function" in verilog, for this specific example?

Tags: function, verilog, fpga

I have 3 values saved on Flip-Flops. During a certain state on a FSM I want to detect which is the bigger value and as a result of this, output into a memory a number.

In a side of the top-module file, I'm writing the function like this:

```
function [1:0] max_val; 
input [7:-24] A, B, C;

begin
    if (A > B)
    begin
        if (A > C)  
            max_val = 2'b01;  
        else
            max_val = 2'b11;
    end 
        else if(B > C)
                    max_val = 2'b10;  
                else
                    max_val = 2'b11;

    else
        max_val = 2b'00;

end
endfunction
```

Then during a state of the FSM I do this:

```
S13:
            begin

                case (max_val(FF_v1, FF_v2, FF_v3))    /// HERE??

                    01:
                            begin
                                mem_out1 = 1;
                            end
                    10:
                            begin
                                mem_out2 = 1;
                            end
                    11:  
                            begin
                                mem_out3 = 1;
                            end
                    00:      
                            begin
                              ...       /// what to do here??
                             end     

                  endcase
             end
```

I would like to ask if I'm defining and calling the function correctly, when I make use of the function, I understand I must use the same name of the function as "variable" and use it to define a case, right? So how do I define the input of that function, just like I did in "HERE???"

Also, if there are only 3 possible answers, and the one the combinations is unused, what to define in default??

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration is right. Why the  `input [7:-24]` changed it to `input [23:0]` . Also the if statement nesting was incorrect.

```
function [1:0] max_val;

input [23:0] A, B, C;

begin
   max_val = 0 ;
    if (A > B)
    begin
        if (A > C)
            max_val = 2'b01;
        else
            max_val = 2'b11;
    end
    else
        if(B > C)
                max_val = 2'b10;
        else
               max_val = 2'b11;  
end
endfunction
```

The case statement is fine . Though the values have to be prefixed with 2'b else it will assume the value to be decimal and not match. The case statement need not always have all the options. You can have only 3 or as many as you need . It is better to add a default statement. You can assign the values to x in the default or just print error for simulation purposes.

```
case ( max_val(a,b,c) )
  2'b01 :  begin
                mem_out_1 = 1;
        end
  2'b10 :  begin
                mem_out_2 = 1;
        end
  2'b11 :  begin
                mem_out_3 = 1;
        end
  // no need for 00 case 
  default : begin
                $display(" error val ");
            end
endcase
```

http://www.testbench.in/TB_18_TASK_AND_FUNCTION.html

Answer (score 1):

When I am coding this type of thing I like to "definitively" state what the outputs are going to be for each case, including the default, even if it is an error.

The point being that you could get a compiler that decides to only assign mem_out1 when you hit the 2'b01 state and leaves it set forever because nothing ever sets it back to zero.  Not sure if that was the point of the design or if it might be undesired behavior.

```
case ( max_val(a,b,c) )
2'b01 :  begin
               {mem_out_3,mem_out_2,mem_out_1} = 3'b001;
       end
2'b10 :  begin
               {mem_out_3,mem_out_2,mem_out_1} = 3'b010;
       end
2'b11 :  begin
               {mem_out_3,mem_out_2,mem_out_1} = 3'b100;
       end
// no need for 00 case 
default : begin
               // {mem_out_3,mem_out_2,mem_out_1} = 3'b000;  // Uncomment if you need to control the output in the event of an error
               $display(" error val ");
           end
endcase
```